# Load on scrolled div

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to load on the content div at a specific point without any animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/utbeuebw/

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed-block">
    Fixed Block
</div>

<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed-block {
    background: red;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.content {
    height: 700px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    background: yellow;   
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var link = $("[href='"+ hash +"']");
    if ( hash == "" ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".content").offset().top
        }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works this way:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var link = $("[href='"+ hash +"']");
if ( hash == "" ) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".content").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/utbeuebw/2/

I removed this: `if(window.location.hash) {` for a couple of reasons:

1 - the closing bracket of that `if` block was missing

2 - it makes no sense checking if an empty string has a boolean value

3 - you already check that here: `if ( hash == "" )`